# Checking if PowerPoint slide is hidden using pptx in python

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm using `python-pptx` to read data from PowerPoint presentations into my python script. In the PowerPoint presentations I'm woring with a view slides are hidden. For my reading process I only want to go through the visible slides. Unfortunately, I didn't find any `isHidden()` or `isVisible()` function in the [documentation](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/slides.html). Is this somehow possible to ask for the visibility status?

Here my code which goes through the slides:

```
from pptx import Presentation
ppt=Presentation(file)
for slide in ppt.slides:
    if side.isVisible(): #does not work!
        #do stuff
```

Comment: In VBA, if the slide has a .SlideShowTransition.Hidden property = True, then it's a hidden slide, ie, not visible.  I don't know whether this is adaptable to Python or not.